# Redis automatically publish new entries

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a web-service that is writing new entries to a Redis-server very frequently, and I have a NodeJS application that will interact with the Redis-server. I realize that I may be asking a question that has been asked in many forms in the past, but I have to ask lest I spend more time going around in circles looking for answers but 'Is there any way for my NodeJS application server to automatically receive new entries?'; similar to how an RSS feed automatically receive new articles.

I understand that there is a publish/subscribe paradigm for Redis, but what I'm having difficulty understanding is "Can Redis automatically publish new entries whenever it receives them?" Also, can Redis automatically publish new entries for a specific key whenever it receives them?

Answer (score 5):

There are redis clients for node.js.  Find one that implements the full protocol, including `subscribe`.

A subscribe (or psubscribe for patterns) uses a `key` to specify the connection channel.  So, for example (using https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)

```
connection.on("message", function (channel, message) {
   if (channel == "myInterestingChannel") {
       console.log(message);
   } else if (channel == "anotherChannel") {
       console.warn(message);
   }
}

connection.subscribe("myInterestingChannel");
connection.subscribe("anotherChannel");
```

Then, when you want your node.js code to know about something in one of these channels, just publish a message.  For instance in python's redis client:

```
connection.publish("myInterestingChannel", "poop goes in the potty");
```

In your question you ask "Also, can Redis automatically publish new entries for a specific key whenever it receives them?"

It can if you publish them on the channel that is being subscribed to.  It cannot, however, publish automatically when you do something like

```
connection.set("myInterestingChannel", "some other message")
```

Instead, if you wanted to store it, and let your node app know, you would do this most easily doing something like:

```
msg = "some other message"
connection.set("some key", msg)
connection.publish("myInterestingChannel", msg)
```